# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity' to type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity'

Tags: c#, .net, security, casting

I have 3 applications that I am trying to test running them locally.

On first one I am running integration test that is calling second ('middle') application that is supposed to create a quote on it's local system and then call third system that is company 'global' system responsible for user management.

It fails while casting `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity` to `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity`

in

```
protected ApplicationAuthorisationService()
{
    CurrentIdentity = (WindowsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
}
```

I have little knowledge of 'global system responsible for user management' since it is being handled by other department still I need to investigate why tests on my local machine are failing.

'middle' application is constructing url and simply calling global one by GET

```
private HttpClient GetHttpClient()
{
    try
    {
        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = this.BaseUri,
        };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        return client;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ILogHelper.LogException(ex, Log, LoggerLevel.Error);
        throw;
    }
}
```

fragment that makes actual call.

```
using (var client = this.GetHttpClient())
{
    client.SetBearerToken(this._token.AccessToken);
    var uri = new Uri(client.BaseAddress, string.Format("api/crmcustomer/?FirstName={0}&Surname={1}&DateOfBirth={2}&PostCode={3}&GetLatestWhenThereAreMultipleResults={4}",
        parameter.FirstName,
        parameter.Surname,
        parameter.DateOfBirth.HasValue ? parameter.DateOfBirth.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : string.Empty,
        parameter.PostCode,
        parameter.GetLatestWhenThereAreMultipleResults));

    this.Log.Info("URI: " + uri);

    this.Log.Debug("parameter.FirstName: " + parameter.FirstName);
    this.Log.Debug("parameter.Surname: " + parameter.Surname);
    if (parameter.DateOfBirth != null)
        this.Log.Debug("parameter.DateOfBirth: " + parameter.DateOfBirth.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    this.Log.Debug("parameter.PostCode: " + parameter.PostCode);
    this.Log.Debug("parameter.GetLatestWhenThereAreMultipleResults: " + parameter.GetLatestWhenThereAreMultipleResults);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CtiResponse>();
}
```

**What could be the cause of this?**

Comment: "so this exception makes little sense" - If the inheritance was the other way around, the exception wouldn't make sense. Apples (WindowsIdentity) are a type of Fruit (ClaimsIdentity). That doesn't mean that you can take any random piece of Fruit and magically turn it into an Apple.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I just had one of those moments where I question myself am I stupid or blind. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those wondering.

Issue was that version of project was [set to .NET 4.0 while](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity(v=vs.100).aspx) this inheritance [get's implemented on .NET 4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx)